# Draw and position "Line" in canvas by modifying the Properties of "Line" in Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, line

I have created a cube and lines using Three.js.

I am trying to position the lines so it appears around the cube as guidelines shown below:

[image]

But I don't understand these properties of line:

```
var lengthVertArray = lengthLineGeometry.vertices;
    lengthVertArray.push(new THREE.Vector3(-240, 50, 0), new THREE.Vector3(30, 120, 0));
```

I randomly changed some values and i was able to position the "line" for "length".

But I want to understand exactly what these properties are, so I can accuratly change them  and position the lines for height and width.

Here is the Fiddle of my cube with guideline: http://jsfiddle.net/boquqL84/3/

Let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are rotating and scaling your cube, everything will be easier if your lines are added to the cube instead of the scene:

```
cube.add(lengthLine);
```

then, since you are creating the cube with

```
cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
```

the cube coordinates will be -0.5 and 0.5. So, your lines could be

```
lengthVertArray.push(new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0.6, 0.6), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.6, 0.6));
```

That is, at a distance of 0.1 from the 0.5 where is the cube, set the line going from -0.5 to 0.5

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/boquqL84/5/)

[demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/boquqL84/8/)

[demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/fo4dcqLd/3/)

Comment: True... thank you for guiding the correct approach!!! But I have a question, what should I do when I change the cube by taking inputs from use.. how should I change the position?? for example if you change the length in your fiddle, the cube override the "width and height" guidelines.

Comment: I am not sure about what is your problem. I think the fiddle works .. May be is it a perspective problem ? I have added another fiddle, with the coordinates set to 0.501. The lines match the cube ..

Comment: Hey one more question, I added 3D text your updated fiddle, to give names to the guidelines like, width, height and length and my Fiddle stopped working, I am not sure what I am missing. Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fo4dcqLd/

Comment: Can you look into it or do you want me to post this into a a new question?

Comment: the three.js that you were using was not the last one. using the latest, it still doesn't work, but the error message is clearer. I have chaned your font to helvetiker, and - the key issue- included the javascript to gemerate it added fiddle

Comment: Hey Nice catch... But I updated the File in fiddle and its still not working... Also I have created the new question for the same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514547/add-3d-text-and-modify-the-proper-ties-to-position-as-per-cube-using-three-js

Comment: Hey Vals , I am getting another issue with the positioning of lines, when adding with Cylinder, can you please look at this question too? Thanks!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534713/draw-straight-line-in-canvas-by-modifying-properties-in-three-js