# Draw Straight “Line” in Canvas by Modifying Properties in Three.JS

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, line

I have created a fiddle which shows the guidelines for length and Diameter for Cylinder

I was able to position the Line for Length.

But m not sure how to change the properties of line so it draws a straight line to show Diameter, like show in the sample below:

```
// Diameter line    
var diameterLineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var diameterVertArray = diameterLineGeometry.vertices;
diameterVertArray.push(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0.5, 0), new THREE.Vector3(-0.3, 0.7, 1));
diameterLineGeometry.computeLineDistances();
var diameterLineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xcc0000
});
var diameterLine = new THREE.Line(diameterLineGeometry, diameterLineMaterial);
cylinder.add(diameterLine);
```

[image]

**The issue I'm getting with this code is, when I change the sixe of cylinder object, the position of "Lines" moves.** The position of Lines shows find when the object is small for eg: 50 x 40, but if I change the dimensions to something like "123x123" the lines position moves.

**Here is the Fiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/b9ge6fr6/7/**

Let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates for the diameter are

```
diameterVertArray.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0.5, 0), new THREE.Vector3(1, 0.5, 0));
```

one length is

```
lengthVertArray.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0.51, 0), new THREE.Vector3(-1, -0.51, 0));
```

and another one is

```
alengthVertArray.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0.5, 1), new THREE.Vector3(0, -0.5, 1));
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9ge6fr6/9/)